# Is it true that $a^k\equiv a^\ell \mod n$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a, b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $k, \ell\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $k\equiv \ell \mod{n}$ and $a\equiv b\mod n$.

Is it true that $a^k\equiv a^\ell \mod n$? If so, prove it. If not, find a counterexample.

I suppose it's true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $b$ in your statement on one side of the congruence?

Comment: It is false. Try random input values that satisfy the conditions; you'll soon hit counterexamples.

Comment: @NeilA. no, that was just part of something else attached to the question

Comment: Did you mean $k\equiv\ell\pmod{\pmb\phi(n)}$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner no, honestly i don't even know what whatever you said means

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function, the number of positive integers up to $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$; Euler's theorem says $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\bmod n$ if $a$ and $n$ are coprime

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What if $n=3$, $k=1$, $\ell=4$ and $a=2$?

Answer (score 0):

No. At least not generally. See: $$y\equiv b\bmod m\implies y=mx+b$$  This means only if y and m share a factor (or x but we generally ignore it) will b share a factor. So if y is a power based on a value that doesn't share a factor, all it's remainders b wont share a factor with the modulus m. Only when the number of of values less than m, that don't share a factor with m, ends up being a divisor of m, will your statement be true. This restricts it pretty much to powers of 2. A few  more edge cases exist like 6, but that's basically it. if they share a factor it will  change for example every value with a factor (2) in common with 8 will hit 0 mod 8 and stay there for any higher powers.It will only hit remainders that have that gcd in common.